# Change ONLY the Image Name/Registry in Kustomize Overlay with Image Transformer

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

For a Kubernetes deployment, given a Kustomize Base like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
...
images:
  - name: developmentregistry.com/myimage:v1.0
```

Is there a way to change only the image registry and retain the o.g. tag with an Overlay **without re-declaring the image** using image transformers?

For example if I use an Overlay like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
...
images:
  - newName: productionregistry.com/myimage
```

The image is deployed as just `productionregistry.com/myimage`— which is not what I want.
How can I make it so my Overlay deployment yields `productionregistry.com/myimage:v1.0`? I cannot find any other posts or any issues about this.
Would I have to use Patches instead of image transformers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I figured it out — Kustomization Yamls are finnicky so you *must* have the right yaml structure.

This works:

**Base**

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
...
images:
  - name: developmentregistry.com/myimage
    newTag: v1.0
```

**Overlay**

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
...
images:
  - name: developmentregistry.com/myimage
    newName: productionregistry.com/myimage
```